# Confused with a proof about Galois theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

So I am self-studying Galois theory and I am currently reading about the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. There is a certain lemma/theorem that is used in the proof of the fundamental theorem which I can not seem to understand the proof of. I have been using this website https://jhavaldar.github.io/notes/2017/10/19/galoistheory1.html (1) to read about it. However, the proof of theorem 2 is omitted so I looked around in my bookmarks and found this source: [http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~martyn/5836/MT5836lecturenotes.pdf](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/%7Emartyn/5836/MT5836lecturenotes.pdf) (2). Here, theorem 2  in the source (1) is equivalent to lemma 6.9 (page 56) in the source (2). The lemma goes as follows:

**Lemma:** Let $K$ be a finite separable extension of a field $F$ and let $H$ be a finite group of $F$-automorphisms of $K$ (that is, $H$ is some subgroup of $Gal(K/F)$). Then $[K:H^*] = |H|$
where $H^* =$ Fix$_K(H)$.

Proof found in source (2): Write $L = H^*$. By the theorem of the primitive element $K = F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in K$. Put $g(X) = \prod_{\varphi \in H} (X - \varphi(\alpha)).$
The proof goes on and shows that $g(X) \in L[X]$.
*The definition of $g(X)$ says that it splits in $K$ and, since $K = F(\alpha)$, we certainly build $K$ by adjoining the roots of $K$ to the subfield $L$. Thus $K$ is the splitting field of $g(X)$ over $L$*...

The last part that is highlighted in italic is the part that I cant seem to grasp. I know that $g(X)$ splits in $K$ by definition, but I do not understand how we build $K$ by adjoining the roots of $K$ to the subfield $L$. What does it mean to adjoin *roots of $K$* to a field? How can this show that $K$ is a splitting field for $g(X)$, i.e it is the minimal field in which $g(X)$ splits in?

Comment: You did not define $g(x)$ in your questions, but I am assuming it is that product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you adjoin an element $\alpha$ to a field $F$, we are talking about the smallest field containing $F$ and $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$, this is spanned as a vector space over $F$ by $1, \alpha, ..., \alpha^{n-1}$.

In your question, $K = F(\alpha)$. Let $\alpha_1 = \alpha$ and write $\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n$ for the roots of $g$. By definition, $\{\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n\} \subseteq K$ and also $L \subseteq K$. Hence, we have that $L(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n) \subseteq K$.

On the other hand, $K = F(\alpha)$ and $L \supseteq F$ so $L(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n) \supseteq L(\alpha) \supseteq F(\alpha) = K$.

So $L(\alpha_1,..., \alpha_n) = K$ and it must be the splitting field of of $g(x)$.